# Slick django debug error?

Tags: python, django, debugging

I've got a Django instance running nicely. An endpoint is secured using jwt . Naturally, I cannot use the browser as it don't know how to send jwt headers, so I use curl which works fine. Now, if something goes wrong, django dump ~2852 lines of html in to my terminal. Can I reduce this somehow? Ideally I would like to just return the same things that's logged when an error returns. Only in `debug=True` of course.

Any pointers?

Comment: Either you use a tool like Postman or you just redirect the output into an HTML file.

Comment: Did you try to wrap an endpoint with try/except block and in case of error return traceback as response?

Comment: I did not try that. It will cause trace back to be sent in production. Not to mention the insane amount of boiler plate

Comment: So you can avoid boilerplate code by creating decorator which wraps any endpoint. In decorator, wrap endpoint with `try/except` block. In `except` block, you have to check if `DEBUG=True` and then return traceback. Otherwise (when `DEBUG=False`), you can ommit  exception handling.

Comment: No, because you still have to decorate each end point.

Comment: Please improve your question (you have mentioned only about single endpoint). And you don't have to decorate all endpoints - you can write your own middleware class which will apply decorator to each view.

Comment: Now we're getting closer to an answer  How would such a middle layer look? Perhaps it's already built-in in Django?

Comment: There is Django documentation about middleware classes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/ (most important, in your case is `process_view` function). I've also found such a middleware, but I didn't tested it: https://gist.github.com/canburak/1578349